# 2 HTML forms within 1 table

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I have a single table that is generated dynamically by looping through a result set and creating rows.  For each row, I need to include 2 checkboxes.  Checkbox A on each row needs to correspond to form A, and checkbox B to form B.

I know this isn't valid, but the below pseudocode is essentially what I want.  I know that in HTML5 I can specify which form an input element belongs to, but my users will primarily be using IE8, which, as far as I can tell, doesn't support this feature.

```
<form name="formA">
<form name="formB">
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>
  <th>
  <th>
 </tr>

LOOP

 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkA" value="1"></td>
  <td>Something</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkB" value="1"></td>
 </tr>

END LOOP

</table>

<input type="submit" /> //formA
<input type="submit" /> //formB
</form> //formA
</form> //formB
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?  I suppose one way would be to use a single form and change the action depending on which submit button is clicked, but I want to see if anyone else has any ideas before I do that.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way is to just make it all in one form and act differently later according to the options selected.

For example

```
<form action="doStuff.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

<!-- LOOP -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkA" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkB" value="1"></td>
    </tr>

<!-- END LOOP -->
  </table>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**doStuff.php**

```
if (isset( $_POST["chkA"] ) ){

  // Checkbox A is checked.

}

if (isset( $_POST["chkB"] ) ){

  // Checkbox B is checked.

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that's what I'd have to do, but was trying to avoid it.

Comment: No problem at all! Sometimes the annoying answer is sadly the easiest. Be sure to mark the response as correct if it is!